# I am getting syntax error on line where childs cursor is declared while running below MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql

Below code I am trying to execute a trigger, but I am getting syntax error in declaration of curesor childs. "CLARE childs CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM jos_image_category where parent_id='processid'; "

```
    `DELIMITER $$  
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`%` TRIGGER image_category_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON jos_image_category   
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
DECLARE cid INT DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE chid INT DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE conid INT DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE pid INT DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE processid INT DEFAULT 0;  
IF OLD.name != NEW.name THEN  
IF new.parent_id != 0 THEN  
set @processid= new.parent_id;  
ELSE  
set @processid=new.id;  
END IF;  
DECLARE childs CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM jos_image_category where parent_id='processid';  
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET record_not_found = 1;  
OPEN childs;  
FETCH childs INTO cid;  
allchild:LOOP   
IF record_not_found THEN   
LEAVE allchild;  
END IF;  
DECLARE content CURSOR FOR SELECT content_id from jos_image_category_map where category_id=cid;  
OPEN content;  
FETCH content into conid;  
allcontent:LOOP   
IF record_not_found THEN   
LEAVE allcontent;  
END IF;  
UPDATE TABLE jos_content set version=version+1 where id=conid and deleted=1 and visible=1 and   publish_down>NOW();  
END LOOP allcontent;  
CLOSE content;  
END LOOP allchild;  
CLOSE childs;  
END IF;  
END $$  
DELIMITER ;
```

'

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
DECLARE childs CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM jos_image_category where parent_id=@processid;
```

instead of

```
DECLARE childs CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM jos_image_category where parent_id='processid';
```

Comment: I tried above said statements as well but same error